# How to set an initially determined zoom level based on data d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code below I've set an intial zoom level after the page have loaded like this:

```
svg.transition().delay(500).duration(750)
    .call(zooming.transform, transform)

function transform() {
    return d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(-210, 0)
        .scale(2);
}
```

The problem is that the `x` value in the `d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x, y)` is hardcoded.

What I want to know is if there's a way to set it so that it always zoom in to, let's say, the last six bars based on the data that's provided? (within reason)

Is using `d3.zoomIdentity` the right way to go about it or is there some other method that would make it easier?

Here's my code:

```js
const data = [
 {name: "A", value: 67},
 {name: "B", value: 92},
 {name: "C", value: 82},
 {name: "D", value: 53},
 {name: "E", value: 20},
 {name: "F", value: 88},
 {name: "G", value: 15},
 {name: "H", value: 94},
 {name: "I", value: 66},
 {name: "J", value: 53}
];

var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
 margin = {top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35},
 width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
 .padding(0.1)

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
 .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

var xAxis = g => g
 .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("fill", "steelblue")
.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
 .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
 .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
 .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
 .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x-axis")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoom(svg) {

 const extent = [
  [margin.left, margin.top], 
  [width - margin.right, height - margin.top]];

 var zooming = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 3])
  .translateExtent(extent)
  .extent(extent)
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
 
 svg.call(zooming);

 svg.transition().delay(500).duration(750)
  .call(zooming.transform, transform)

 function transform() {
  return d3.zoomIdentity
   .translate(-210, 0)
   .scale(2);
 }
 
 function zoomed() {

  x.range([
   margin.left, width - margin.right]
   .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));

  svg.selectAll(".bars rect")
   .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
   .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: auto;
 width: 850px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart" width="400" height="420"></svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can get the last six bars by simply getting the x position of the sixth last:

```
-x(data[data.length - 6].name)
```

Since you're scaling by two, we have to multiply it accordingly:

```
-x(data[data.length - 6].name) * 2
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
const data = [
 {name: "A", value: 67},
 {name: "B", value: 92},
 {name: "C", value: 82},
 {name: "D", value: 53},
 {name: "E", value: 20},
 {name: "F", value: 88},
 {name: "G", value: 15},
 {name: "H", value: 94},
 {name: "I", value: 66},
 {name: "J", value: 53}
];

var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
 margin = {top: 35, left: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35},
 width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
 .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
 .padding(0.1)

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
 .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

var xAxis = g => g
 .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "bars")
 .attr("fill", "steelblue")
.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
 .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
 .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
 .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.value))
 .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x-axis")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoom(svg) {

 const extent = [
  [margin.left, margin.top], 
  [width - margin.right, height - margin.top]];

 var zooming = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 3])
  .translateExtent(extent)
  .extent(extent)
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
 
 svg.call(zooming);

 svg.transition().delay(500).duration(750)
  .call(zooming.transform, transform);
    
 var xValue = -x(data[data.length - 6].name)*2;

 function transform() {
  return d3.zoomIdentity
   .translate(xValue, 0)
   .scale(2);
 }
 
 function zoomed() {

  x.range([
   margin.left, width - margin.right]
   .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));

  svg.selectAll(".bars rect")
   .attr("x", d => x(d.name))
   .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  svg.selectAll(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: auto;
 width: 850px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart" width="400" height="250"></svg>
```

Comment: Very nice solution Thanks